# How to draw multiple binary regions using imfreehand

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, drawing

I am trying to create a user-controlled binary mask using `imfreehand`. I am trying to allow to user to select multiple regions instead of a single region. Once a region is drawn on the image `tophatImage`, the binary version of the selected region appears on the image `totalBinary`. So far so good.

The problem is that, when the next region needs to be drawn, the previously drawn region in `tophatImage` disappears. This can be a problem since the user cannot see what regions s/he has drawn and cannot delete drawn regions. The binary version of the previously drawn regions in `totalBinary` remain intact, so that is not a problem.

I think the problem originates from the line `subplot(1,2,1); imshow(tophatImage)` inside the `for-loop`. The image `tophatImage` is being reset every time a new region needs to be drawn. As you can see in the first image below, there is not drawn image remaining as in the third image.

***Original Erroneous Code***

```
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(tophatImage)

hFH = imfreehand();
binaryImage = createMask(hFH);
totalBinary = false(size(histogramEq));

for k = 1:5
    totalBinary = totalBinary | binaryImage;
    subplot(1,2,2); imshow(totalBinary); drawnow

    subplot(1,2,1); imshow(tophatImage)
    hFH = imfreehand();
    binaryImage = createMask(hFH);
end
```

***Corrected Code***

With the corrected code, how can I make it so that when a region is deleted from `tophatImage`, it is updated onto `totalBinary`?

```
for k = 1:5
    totalBinary = totalBinary | binaryImage;
    subplot(1,2,2); imshow(totalBinary); drawnow

    subplot(1,2,1); %imshow(tophatImage) % <-- Remove this
    hFH = imfreehand();
    binaryImage = createMask(hFH);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple error.  In your loop, after you call `subplot(1,2,1);` remove the call to `imshow(tophatImage);`.  This is erasing your figure's contents and showing just the image itself. If you want the contours drawn by you with `imfreehand` to remain, don't call `imshow`.  With `imfreehand`, the contours should remain until you either close the figure, or change the contents within this `subplot`.

To be absolutely sure you know what I'm talking about:

```
for k = 1:5
    totalBinary = totalBinary | binaryImage;
    subplot(1,2,2); imshow(totalBinary); drawnow

    subplot(1,2,1); %imshow(tophatImage) % <-- Remove this
    hFH = imfreehand();
    binaryImage = createMask(hFH);
end
```

Comment: It is working now, but when I delete a region, it doesn't seem to be updated onto `totalBinary` for some reason and gives an error.

Comment: I tried it on my end and it works.  Both the contours and the mask get updated.

Comment: Your code doesn't delete regions. It only appends. Please update your post with this code to delete regions and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I don't think a code is necessary for deleting a region since when you right click on the drawn region in `tophatImage`, it shows the option to delete the drawn region.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul If that's the case, removing contours through the UI requires you writing an event handler for that, which is more complicated.  Simply deleting contours through the UI does not update the mask.  I unfortunately don't know how to do that and that's honestly a separate question. I believe I have addressed your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.